# Configure Routing and Remote Access, Windows Server 2016

Tags: routing, windows-server-2016, remote-access

I have a Windows Server 2016 and it is a virtual machine on a VPS.

I got this error message when I tried to configure **Routing and Remote Access**

> Incoming connections are currently enabled on *server*. before you can configure routing and remote access on *server* you must open network connections and delete incoming connections.

I disabled all network connections but it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea what is the problem?

P.S: I have access to it via VNC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this on a Microsoft forum as a fix, might be helpful:

1. Run the command prompt as administrator.
2. Enter the command

REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\rasman /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

3. Enter the command

REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\remoteaccess /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

4. Restart your system

---

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2d22e0b6-2e9f-41da-9f46-1a002c57bdc6/cannot-create-new-incoming-connection?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: what does powershell `Get-NetAdapter -Name * -IncludeHidden | format-list` say? and `Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | Select-Object -Property LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State | Sort-Object LocalPort |ft`

Comment: You could also try to reset the network stack: Type ipconfig /release and press Enter.
Type ipconfig /flushdns and press Enter.
Type ipconfig /renew and press Enter. (This will stall for a moment.)
Type netsh int ip reset and press Enter. (Don’t restart yet.)
Type netsh winsock reset and press Enter.